# Radio Button widget not working inside AlertDialog Widget in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want user to select the option given in Radio Button before moving to second page in My Flutter Application. I'm showing Radio button widget inside Alertdialog it shows but radio button not changed after selecting.

Everything State Class

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.create),
      onPressed: () {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Select Grade System and No of Subjects"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                    Radio(value: 0, groupValue: groupValue, onChanged: selectRadio),
                    Radio(value: 1, groupValue: groupValue, onChanged: selectRadio),
                    ],
            ));
      },
    ),
```

selectRadio Function

```
void selectRadio(int value)
{
setState(() {
  groupValue=value;
});
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the peice of code (`build` method)? Have you tried clicking directly on radio button not on the label?

Comment: Please add the code snippet of what you have done.

Comment: @ChennaReddy code added

Comment: @Harshapulikollu code added

Comment: Why are you using Radio Buttons for actions (why not normal buttons)?   If that is the only way, then better move these radio buttons into another stateful widget as you are playing with the state there.

Comment: showDialog creates new context and that setState on the calling widget therefore won't affect the dialog

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said the above comment **showDialog creates new context and that setState on the calling widget therefore won't affect the dialog** 
You can create new stateful widget naming MyDialog.[Checkout this gist](https://gist.github.com/jonahwilliams/25fa99b6b73fdcbd58ac85585343bbd0) such that you can get it(*it uses dropdown but you can implement radio widget in same way*).

Comment: Thank you, its working and i used this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17044  so whenever using showdialog we need to create statefulwidget?

Comment: No not every time like, If you want alert user like "Press OKAY to exit" with okay and cancel button then you don't need to create a stateful widget. If you want to make some UI render/ changes  inside the dialog like you did for radio widget then you have to use stateful widget. Else just for alert/error/about messages you don't need to create a stateful widget.

Answer (score 65):

I had the same issue. I solved it by using this:

```
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    int selectedRadio = 0;
    return AlertDialog(
      content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
              return Radio<int>(
                value: index,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                onChanged: (int value) {
                  setState(() => selectedRadio = value);
                },
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
```

Comment: nice, very straight to the answer!!

Comment: this worked for me straight forward and easy to implement.....

Comment: great... its working

Answer (score 0):

[custom language popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGEjG.png)
You need to create separate statefulwidget class to handle state of radio button. Refer [this](https://programmershelpdes.wixsite.com/website/post/flutter-custom-dialog-with-radio-button-lists) example